# json data in variable jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I am sending Json data like this

```
var books = bookInfoService.GetAllBookInfo(1);
            var bookList = from w in books
                           from x in w.BookAuthors
                           select new
                           {
                               authorName = x.Authors.Name

                           };

var bookShelfs = bookShelfService.GetAllBookShelfs(1);
var jsonData = from w in bookShelfs select new { w.Id, w.Price, w.BarcodeId, w.BookInfos_s.Title, w.BookInfos_s.BookCategories.CategoryName,bookList};
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In the Jqgrid i have a column to show value of authorName.Code of that column is like below.

```
{ name: 'authorName', width: 180, align: 'center', editable: false },
```

and my firebug showing data like

**[{"Id":1,"Price":23,"BarcodeId":1000,"Title":"HeadFirst C#","CategoryName":"Book","bookList":[{"autorId":1,"authorName":"Skiena"}]}**

I want the get the author name in authorName column.But how can i do this?
Is it possible to pass the authorName in the jsonData?Like

```
var jsonData = from w in bookShelfs select new { w.Id, w.Price, w.BarcodeId, w.BookInfos_s.Title, w.BookInfos_s.BookCategories.CategoryName} from s in books select new{s.Authors.Name};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that info directly from the json representation of the grid.
example :

```
//get the data(json) of the grid
var gridData = yourJqgrid.getRowData();
var myRandomCell = gridData[rowNumber].cellName
```

Also checkout :http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods
Hope this helps!

Comment: i don't understand your solution

Comment: you grid has an json data representation like suppose we have a table with 2 columns : A and B and 2 rows 1 and 2. To get the data from the 2B cell we use myJqGrid.getRowData[2].B also before moving on consider reading a thing or two about **JSON** that will clear things.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/json/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON will get you started